# Scoring clarification for end of campaign/day of rest

Tags: libertalia

In Libertalia, the last paragraph of page 9 in the rulebook states:

> The players then move their score token a number of spaces equal to their **total fortune** (in doubloons) on the score track.  Their final score will be the **sum of all doubloons won** during the three campaigns.

Since you start each campaign with 10 doubloons, I can see this interpreted two ways:

- Total fortune method: count all doubloons at end of campaign; this is your score for that campaign
- Doubloons won method: count all doubloons then subtract the 10 starting doubloons (meaning you only score your 'winnings' or profit from the campaign)

As long as you keep the scoring method consistent, both seem to work fine.

My question is: are there any other references in the rules that would indicate one method should be used over the other?

Comment: Is there a reason the difference is important if either counting method is always equivalent?

Comment: As a new player it's not obvious that either method will work; after the scoring phase everyone turns in all their doubloons and money resets, but you don't know this unless you read ahead in the rules.  So I was hoping to get a definitive answer on the meaning of this confusing paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules don't make the distinction between doubloons won and doubloons in your possession. Whoever wrote the rules probably didn't consider that someone might take this phrase extra literally.

Logically it makes sense to not subtract the 10 starting doubloons because:

1) Like you mentioned, it doesn't matter either way and 
       subtracting doubloons each time is a completely unnecessary hassle.

2) You could end up with less doubloons than you started with. In this case you won't be able to subtract ten doubloons. Because it's possible to lose doubloons, it could be argued that any doubloons that you kept have been `won`.